# how do I pass count integer into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Here is where I set up my var adultOptions and in this var you will see name="adult'+i+'Name" /> I want that i to be the loop number you see below.

Any ideas?! Thank you

```
var adultOptions =
'<input type="text"'+
'placeholder="First &amp; Last Name"'+
'required name="adult'+i+'Name"/>'


$('#adults').on('change',function(i){
    numberAppend = $('#adults').val();
    for(i=0; i<numberAppend; i++){
    $(adultOptions).appendTo('#adultOptions');
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly correct with your method. What you are lacking is, *maybe* the knowledge that a function can be stored in a variable in javascript.

So, *now with this knowledge*, you can make `adultOptions` point to a function, like this:

```
var adultOptions = function(i) {
return '<input type="text"'+
'placeholder="First &amp; Last Name"'+
'required name="adult'+i+'Name"/>';
}
```

and, then use it like this:

```
$('#adults').on('change',function(i){
    numberAppend = $('#adults').val();
    for(i=0; i<numberAppend; i++){
    $(adultOptions(i)).appendTo('#adultOptions');
  }    
});
```

Comment: Stoic, your absolutely right thank you! One of those nights when I am a little too close to what I'm working on. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your string is being defined outside of your for loop (where i is being defined). Put it inside and you should be good.